# Eloquent update json column with dot key

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I can't find any information on how to properly update json values with dots in the key. Can you tell me where to clarify this information and how to do it? Is it possible to do this by means Eloquent? Or only through a raw request?

in db column state, we have this data

```json
{"2.7":35,"2.9":24,"2.95":8.99}
```

I have tried. With or without shielding. Values with dots are saved successfully. Keys with dots cannot be obtained and updated.
don't work

```php
Something::find(1005)->update(['state->2.95'=>8.7]);
Something::find(1005)->update(['state->2\.95'=>8.7]);
```

The operation is successful, but there is no result. The value does not change.

Having studied the operations that Eloquent. I've discovered several methods that split the key using a dot. There is also a method that checks whether this key is populated. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes::isFillable

```php
  /**
     * Determine if the given attribute may be mass assigned.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isFillable($key)
    {
        if (static::$unguarded) {
            return true;
        }

        // If the key is in the "fillable" array, we can of course assume that it's
        // a fillable attribute. Otherwise, we will check the guarded array when
        // we need to determine if the attribute is black-listed on the model.
        if (in_array($key, $this->getFillable())) {
            return true;
        }

        // If the attribute is explicitly listed in the "guarded" array then we can
        // return false immediately. This means this attribute is definitely not
        // fillable and there is no point in going any further in this method.
        if ($this->isGuarded($key)) {
            return false;
        }

        return empty($this->getFillable()) &&
            ! str_contains($key, '.') &&
            ! str_starts_with($key, '_');
    }
```

It is he who is responsible for the fact that a value with a key with a dot cannot be written down. It defines it as not writable.

Comment: Is raw query an option?

Comment: Now I am inclined to this conclusion. That this can only be done through a raw query. Because this cannot be done using convenient eloquent ->update method.

Comment: why not modify the state property of your model and save it back? but a better solution for the future would be to split this json column into it's own table

Comment: From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment-json-columns): "When assigning JSON columns, each column's mass assignable key must be specified in your model's $fillable array." This means you need `state->2.95` listed in `$fillable`.

Comment: Or if you're feeling dangerous, you can make the model unguarded. But if you're in the situation of not knowing what the possible keys for your data object are, then they should not be keys at all.

Comment: @kris-gjika

Yes, now, due to this problem, we have to do this. Those. I'm updating an entire column state. And not by individual keys. And working with keys using PHP or a Java script. Almost as you suggested. I will take note of the recommendations for organizing data. This question was asked to understand whether it is even possible to do what I want the way I want. I thought it was just a question of dot escaping and syntax, but apparently the solution lies in a new way of organizing data or raw queries.

Answer (score 0):

To perform any kind of updates, all columns (with or without dots) should be specified in the model's `fillable` property. This includes JSON columns, according to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#mass-assignment-json-columns):

> When assigning JSON columns, each column's mass assignable key must be specified in your model's $fillable array. For security, Laravel does not support updating nested JSON attributes when using the guarded property:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * The attributes that are mass assignable.
>  *
>  * @var array
>  */
> protected $fillable = [
>     'options->enabled',
> ];
> ```

So you should have the following in your model definition:

```php
class Something extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ["state->2.7", "state->2.9", "state->2.95"];
}
```

And then, as you can see from the framework code you posted, your update should work as expected.

---

In that same framework code you can also see another option: making the model unguarded. This is dangerous and generally not recommended. But, [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#allowing-mass-assignment) says:

> If you would like to make all of your attributes mass assignable, you may define your model's $guarded property as an empty array. If you choose to unguard your model, you should take special care to always hand-craft the arrays passed to Eloquent's fill, create, and update methods:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
>  *
>  * @var array
>  */
> protected $guarded = [];
> ```

---

If you're considering unguarding the model, I think you would be better off reconsidering your data structure. For example, if you don't know that your object will always contain the "2.7", "2.9", and "2.95" keys, they should not be used as keys. A better approach would be to store data like this:

```json
[[2.7, 35], [2.9, 24], [2.95, 8.99]]
```

Which does make updating the data more complex, but again perhaps reconsidering the storage mechanism (JSON columns) would be in order.

Comment: Thank you. Your idea of storing keys is very interesting and valuable. And this - "But if you're in the situation of not knowing what the possible keys for your data object are, then they should not be keys at all" - useful idea too.

As for filled and protected fields, yes, I knew this question earlier, to solve the issue (for test purposes) I use protected $guarded = []; without filling. but this doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I was thinking about moving this column into a separate linked table | id  | name | value | relation_id |, but it seems to me that this approach is more voluminous when there are a lot of values